# Discretize continuous target variable using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, classification, joblib

I have to discretize into at least 5 bins a continuous target variable in order to lower the complexity of a classification model using the sklearn library

In order to do this, I've used the KBinsDiscretizer but I don't know how can I split in balanced parts the dataset now that I've discretized the target variable.
This is my code:

```
X = df.copy()
y = X.pop('shares') 

# scaling the dataset so all data in the same range
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

discretizer = preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=5,  encode='ordinal', strategy='uniform')
y_discretized = discretizer.fit_transform(y.values.reshape(-1, 1))

# is this correct?
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, shuffle=True, stratify=y_discretized)
```

For completeness, I'm trying to recreate a less complex model than the one showed in: [1] K. Fernandes, P. Vinagre and P. Cortez. A Proactive Intelligent Decision Support System for Predicting the Popularity of Online News. Proceedings of the 17th EPIA 2015 - Portuguese Conference on Artificial Intelligence, September, Coimbra, Portugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `y_train` and `y_test` are parts of `y`, which has (it seems) the original continuous values.  So you're ending up fitting multiclass classification models, with probably *lots* of different classes, which likely causes the crashes.

I assume what you wanted is

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y_discretized, test_size=0.33, shuffle=True, stratify=y_discretized)
```

Whether discretizing a continuous target to turn a regression into a classification is a topic for another site, see e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/90297/55122